# Using methods of a class from another in python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, instance-methods

I'm working through 'Dive Into Python' on Google App Engine and came across this error while attempting to call one class's methods from another:

```
ERROR __init__.py:463] create() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 35, in get
    dal.create("sample-data");
  File "dataAccess/dal.py", line 27, in create
    self.data_store.create(data_dictionary);
TypeError: create() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Here's my main class:

```
# filename: main.py

from dataAccess.dal import DataAccess

class MySampleRequestHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
"""Configured to be invoked for a specific GET request"""

    def get(self):
        dal = DataAccess();
        dal.create("sample-data"); # problem area
```

`MySampleRequestHandler.get()` tries to instantiate and invoke `DataAccess` which is defined else where:

```
# filename: dal.py

from dataAccess.datastore import StandardDataStore

class DataAccess:
    """Class responsible for wrapping the specific data store"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.data_store = None;

        data_store_setting = config.SETTINGS['data_store_name'];                
        if data_store_setting == DataStoreTypes.SOME_CONFIG:
            self.data_store = StandardDataStore();

        logging.info("DataAccess init completed.");

    def create(self, data_dictionary):
        # Trying to access the data_store attribute declared in __init__
        data_store.create(data_dictionary);
```

I thought I could call `DataAccess.create()` with 1 parameter for its argument, especially according to how Dive into Python notes about class method calls:

> When defining your class methods, you must explicitly list self as the first 
>       argument for each method, including `__init__`. When you call a method of an 
>       ancestor class from within your class, you must include the self argument. 
>       But when you call your class method from outside, you do not specify anything 
>       for the self argument; you skip it entirely, and Python automatically adds the 
>       instance reference for you.

Comment: How is the `StandardDataStore.create()` method defined? What are the arguments it expects?

Comment: Yes, the error is with the `data_store` object's `create()` method, not the `DataAccess` one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `self.data_store.create(data_dictionary)`, the `self.data_store` refers to the object created by `self.data_store = StandardDataStore()` in the `__init__` method.

It looks like the `create` method of a `StandardDataStore` object doesn't expect an additional argument.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `self.data_store.create(data_dictionary);`

Comment: I tried that but got a similar error: ERROR __init__.py:463] create() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 35, in get
    dal.create("sample-data");
  File "dal.py", line 27, in create
    self.data_store.create(data_dictionary);
TypeError: create() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)